# in php code echo is not working mean it not fetching the data from the database? mydonor_submit is button where id: "mmyBtn" data-target: "#myModal":

Tags: php

[Error is showing like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZiqy.png)my modal-content is working but the fetching data is not showing in the popup modal. please help me to solve the problem.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['mydonor_submit']))
        {
            $var = $_POST['bloodgroup2'];
            $query = "select * from donate where 
bloodgroup='$var'";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            $row = 
 mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        }
?>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal">

      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <p><label> Full Name :</label><?php echo $row['fullname'];?></p>

      </div>

    </div>
```

No error is showing

Comment: `'".$var."'` update that

Comment: where ?? in which line

Comment: Your code is _wide open_ to sql injection attacks. Please work through a few tutorials about how to correctly use the combination of "prepared statements" and "parmeter binding" to prevent that well known and common attack on we pages.